# How to install XULRunner for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xulrunner

I'm using the *SWT browser widget* to develop an application in *Java* with *Eclipse* ("Kepler").

Now I want to use the Mozilla API and downloaded the latest *sdk* from XULRunner from this site: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/latest/

How can I tell Eclipse to use *XULRunner* so I can use the following code line?

```
browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
```

Any suggestions on the same are highly appreciated.

Comment: See http://www.eclipse.org/atf/old/downloads/base_files/manualXulrunner_section.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295060/embedding-xulrunner-application-on-java.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the first site but I got the following error: Could not parse application.ini. Then I found a thread on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567581/xulrunner-error-couldnt-parse-application-ini) where someone said, that it is not necessary to register it. So how can I tell Eclipse to use XULRunner? Comment to the 2nd link: I don't want to use another class which uses SWT and I think its not necessary to do so and change the existing classes I have embedded...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWT is not supporting 'latest' XULRunner.
See [Bug 327696 – [Browser] implement support for xulrunner >= 4.0](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327696)

See also The SWT FAQ, [Q: How do I specify the default type of native renderer that is used by the Browser?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault) or [Q: How do I explicitly use Mozilla as the Browser's underlying renderer?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla) or so.

For example,

1. Download the last one which is available on eclipse from 
   http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0.4esr/sdk/
2. Extract it to C:\
3. Edit your app's Run Configuration->Arguments->VM Arguments, add following argument.
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\xulrunner

Comment: Great - got it! Your example was very helpful :) You should only just add a "\bin" behind the given path cause it's a sdk: -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\xulrunner\bin

Comment: How should I know which is `last one which is available on eclipse`? According to this bug report - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422561 I tried 24.0b10...

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Debian Wheezy.

This is how I circunvented the trouble:

1. Make sure you don't have any package named xulrunner:

   $ dpkg --list | fgrep xulrunner
2. Install xulrunner-10.0  ( DO NOT install xulrunner-17.0 )

   $ apt-get install xul-runner-10.0
3. Insert the following line in your eclipse.ini file:

   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/lib/xulrunner-10.0
4. Restart Eclipse. It should pick up the new configuration and should work as expected.

Comment: Where do you find xulrunner-10.0?

Comment: You can find all xulrunner releases [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/).

Comment: I've tried with an app based in Eclipse Kepler, to use http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0.4esr/runtimes/xulrunner-10.0.4esr.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 , but the JVM crashes when trying to instantiate a Mozilla browser.  Should I try version 10.0.0 instead of 10.0.4esr?