# Vaadin Visual Designer not working

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I created a Vaadin 7 project in Eclipse Kepler for Java EE. I am having difficulty in opening the Vaadin Visual Designer.  I am using Win 7 64 bit, Java JDK 7, Vaadin plugin for eclipse, IveDE, Apache Tomcat 7.

The source tab for the visual designer is accessible but the Design tab is not available at the bottom left corner.  Anyone faced this issue before?  I might be missing some files, but I tried updating eclipse and resolved Ive without any change.

Please advice.  Thanks in advance for the help.

It is the same issue as described in this post,

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3655464

Found the workaround, at http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12141

add this to the ecilpse.ini file

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\
```

However I still get a pop up message in eclipse saying that is cannot detect XULRunner 1.9

Any suggesstions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same message as I logged here - https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/4730252/7730928 (yes, my configuration was different - Win8, maven and so on) ?

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994805/how-to-install-xulrunner-for-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Did you update the path to your actual xul runner location? For example, if you extracted the archive directly to C:, your path will look like this:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\xulrunner
```

You probably don't have all the xul runner files directly on C:.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the Vaadin Plugin for Eclipse installs the xulrunner by default. I say this because on this blog [Using Vaadin Eclipse Plugin under Win7 x64](http://ralf.schaeftlein.de/2013/05/03/using-vaadin-eclipse-plugin-under-win7-x64/) I found xulrunner installment listed as a required step.

Comment: No, plugin do not install xulrunner by default (at least when I tried two months ago). Interesting that that blog recommends installing 32-bit Eclipse and Java if I understood it well...

Answer (score -1):

Just add to the `eclipse.ini` this:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\xulrunner\xulrunner.exe
```

Eclipse will show an error, just ignore that as designer will be working then.

Comment: Don't have to point to the .exe .. just the path.
And the error message is because the installer is 32bin, but as you said, it can be ignored